# how to display image in react fetched from node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, axios

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class DisplyDish extends Component {
  state = { posts: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8888/api/v1/dish") //returns promise
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ posts: response.data });
        console.log("response:", response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("err:", err);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>title</th>
              <th>type</th>

              <th>weight</th>
              <th>originalPrice</th>
              <th>offerPrice</th>
              <th>description</th>
              <th>quantity</th>
              <th>status</th>
              <th>rating</th>
              <th>image</th>
            </tr>
            {this.state.posts.map(post => {
              return (
                <tr key={post.id}>
                  <td>{post.id}</td>

                  <td> {post.title}</td>
                  <td> {post.type}</td>

                  <td> {post.weight}</td>
                  <td>{post.originalPrice}</td>
                  <td>{post.offerPrice}</td>
                  <td>{post.description}</td>
                  <td>{post.quantity}</td>
                  <td>{post.status}</td>
                  <td>{post.rating}</td>

                  <td>
                    <img
                      src={"http://localhost:8888/api/v1/dish/" + post.image}
                      alt="image"
                    />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplyDish;
```

and this is what i'm getting in console

```
id: 3
​​
image: "uploads/dish/image_1581159803092.jpg"
```

​​

Comment: `<img
                  src=require("http://localhost:8888/api/v1/dish/" + post.image})
                  alt="image"
                />`

Comment: do you know how the images are served from the backend? .. also do you see any errors in ur browser n/w tab? ... also take the image url and run it in ur browser... update the qn with more info...

Comment: Please give us some more info. Look in your console/network tab, is there any signal the request for these images returned a 404 not found error?